# Why can I not overwrite a certain field through Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC application which uses Entity Framework. I want to change the field `CreatedOn` in the `Users` table.

The following code

```
    using (var db = new MainDB())
    {   
        var theUser = db.Users.Single(u => u.LoginName == model.User.LoginName);
        theUser.CreatedOn = new DateTime(2017, 1, 1); // this does not save
        theUser.CF20 = "test20";
        db.SaveChanges();   
    }
```

changes the field `CF20` to "test20" but it doesn't change the `CreatedOn` field.

I assume that the `CreatedOn` field is being given some special status and functionality somewhere which fills it with a timestamp upon creation of the record, and which prevents it from being changed thereafter.

I can't find where it does this in the code, so I assume it is somewhere in Entity Framework models, settings, etc.

**Where can I look to find out where it is being set and how I can change it after it has been set?**

### Addendum

For instance, I found in an .edmx file under `<EntityType Name="Users">` the line `<Property Name="CreatedOn" Type="datetime" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Computed" />` and change it to `<Property Name="CreatedOn" Type="datetime" Nullable="false" />` but it still computes the date as datetime and will not changed it.

And outputting the raw SQL, I see that in the `update` statement, it leaves `CreatedOn` out: my SQL output shows:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Users]
SET [LoginName] = @0,
    [Password] = @1,
    [PasswordSalt] = @2,
    [LastLoginIP] = NULL,
    [Status] = @3,
    [Email] = @4,
    [FailedLoginAttempts] = NULL,
    [CF01] = NULL,
    [CF02] = NULL,
    [CF03] = NULL,
    [CF04] = NULL,
    [CF05] = NULL,
    [CF06] = NULL,
    [CF07] = NULL,
    [CF08] = NULL,
    [CF09] = NULL,
    [CF10] = NULL,
    [LanguageID] = @5,
    [CF11] = NULL,
    [CF12] = NULL,
    [CF13] = NULL,
    [CF14] = NULL,
    [CF15] = NULL,
    [CF16] = NULL,
    [CF17] = NULL,
    [CF18] = NULL,
    [CF19] = @6,
    [CF20] = @7,
    [MustChangePassword] = NULL
WHERE ([ID] = @8)
```

Comment: Does the Users come from your code or from ASP.Net Identity? Which version of EF are you using?

Comment: The class is generated, i.e. has the notice "<auto-generated> This code was generated from a template..." but I didn't set it up. In that class, I don't see an attribute above the definition `public System.DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }`. In my `packages.config` file I find `<package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />`.

Comment: Have you tried looking in the `DbContext` class to see if there's something happening in there? Also have you tried marking the entity modified `db.Entry(theUser).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;` before calling `db.SaveChanges();`?

Comment: We have a `MainDB` class which inhererits DbContext and overrides SaveChanges, but nothing specifically handles `CreatedOn` for the `Users` table in there. I added `db.Entry(theUser).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;` but it saves as before: no changes to the `CreatedOn` value.

Comment: Are you using `AsNoTracking()` or `db.Entry(entry).State = EntitiyState.Detached` anywhere?

Comment: Can you try [this](https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/08/ef6-sql-logging-part-1-simple-logging/) to see the raw query which is being executed by ef

Comment: Can you chck that `SaveCahnges` and `SaveChangesAsync` don't be overriden into `DbContext`? If yes, then look some weird logic related to that property.

Comment: Wurd, I find `AsNoTracking` used once in our application in another controller, but not where my code is. I don't find `EntitiyState.Detached` anywhere.

Comment: Izzy, I added `db.Database.Log = Console.Write;` to my code but don't see any output in my output window. Or where else would I see the output in Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, CodeNotFound, `SaveChanges()` is overridden in `MainDB`, but has only a few lines which calls base.SaveChanges()` and throws a custom exception, but nothing about `OnCreated`.

Comment: `db.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);` should output in the output window as long as the project is running in `Debug` mode. Ensure in the output window you have `Show output from: Debug` select from the dropdown. I have just used `db.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s)` and can see the raw sql query in the output window

Comment: For instance, I found in an .edmx file under `<EntityType Name="Users">` the line `<Property Name="CreatedOn" Type="datetime" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Computed" />` and changed it to `<Property Name="CreatedOn" Type="datetime" Nullable="false" />` but it still computes the date as datetime and will not changed it.

Comment: Izzy, my SQL output shows: `UPDATE [dbo].[Users] SET [LoginName] = @0, [Password] = @1, [PasswordSalt] = @2,  [LastLoginIP] = NULL, [Status] = @3, [Email] = @4, [FailedLoginAttempts] = NULL, [CF01] = NULL, [CF02] = NULL, [CF03] = NULL, [CF04] = NULL, [CF05] = NULL, [CF06] = NULL, [CF07] = NULL, [CF08] = NULL, [CF09] = NULL, [CF10] = NULL, [LanguageID] = @5, [CF11] = NULL, [CF12] = NULL, [CF13] = NULL, [CF14] = NULL, [CF15] = NULL, [CF16] = NULL, [CF17] = NULL, [CF18] = NULL, [CF19] = @6, [CF20] = @7, [MustChangePassword] = NULL WHERE ([ID] = @8)` which leaves `CreateOn` out.

Comment: Then right after that it, it outputs: `SELECT [CreatedOn] FROM [dbo].[Users] WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [ID] = @8`.

Comment: That's very weird behavior, I have never come across anything like it before, I'm sorry I don't know what else to suggest

Comment: Ok, PARTIAL SUCCESS: I found another .edmx file which had under <EntityType Name="Users"> the line <Property Name="CreatedOn" Type="datetime" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Computed" /> and changed it to <Property Name="CreatedOn" Type="datetime" Nullable="false" />. But while this allows me to change the field value now, it doesn't set it with a time stamp on creation, but rather sets the value as `0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000`. How can I make it both (1) set the timestamp on creation, but (2) also allow me to change the field afterward.

Comment: Is the database column a computed property or one with a default value? Then that will be recorded in the EDMX and EF will refuse to update. It'll probably be recorded in about three places as well. Remove it from all places. Then do consider that when you create an entity of this kind, you'll now have to provide `DateTime.Now` for that property or it'll be `DateTime.MinValue`.

Comment: CodeCaster, yes, under `Default Value or Binding` for this column, I find `(getdate())`. How can I make it so it is only computed on create and otherwise can be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a computed column in SQL Server, so there's nowhere in your code where it's actually being set - it's being done on the server when the row's initially added. EF will not include computed columns in update queries and will read back the column(s) after the update query to load in the potentially updated value from the data store.

**Update after discussion:**

Here's a minimal solution where the Default value is correctly updated on demand.

First create a new table on SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DateDefaultTest](
    [AnId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [SomeField] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DateDefaultTest] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AnId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DateDefaultTest] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_DateDefaultTest_CreatedOn]  DEFAULT (getutcdate()) FOR [CreatedOn]
GO
```

This has an ID field as auto-incrementing primary key, a string field and the `CreatedOn` field we're interested in. We've added a DEFAULT constraint to set this to the current UTC date and time.

Next, create a console application, add EF via NuGet and set up the DbContext as per usual. I've called my context `DefaultTestEntities`.

The generated code for the entity is as follows:

```
public partial class DateDefaultTest
{
    public int AnId { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string SomeField { get; set; }
}
```

In the EF diagram's property page for the `CreatedOn` field, nothing has been changed.

Use the following code to add a couple of rows:

```
using (var db = new DefaultTestEntities())
{
    db.DateDefaultTests.Add(new DateDefaultTest
    {
         SomeField = "Bananas"
    });
    db.DateDefaultTests.Add(new DateDefaultTest
    {
         SomeField = "Apples",
    });

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

These should appear in the table with the current date and time set as expected.

As you've discovered, should you attempt to set `CreatedOn` manually when inserting a new row, this will not work because of the SQL Server constraint. For example:

```
db.DateDefaultTests.Add(new DateDefaultTest
{
     SomeField = "Pears",
     CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1)
});
```

Will result in a nonsense '0001-01-01' date being set.

You will have to update an existing row if you want to set `CreatedOn` explicitly. To do this:

```
db.DateDefaultTests
    .Where(x => x.SomeField == "Bananas")
    .First()
    .CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1);
db.SaveChanges();
```

If this doesn't apply to your situation, I'd recommend you:

- Check your column in SQL Server to ensure the value is not computed
- Regenerate your model
- Confirm that you have no EF overrides in your code which could be affecting the value when the entity is saved

Apologies for the comment where I said EF would not update Default columns. This was incorrect and only applies to the initial insert.

**Update - Required Settings:**

[image: SQL Server CreatedOn Settings]

[image: EDMX CreatedOn Settings]

Comment: Under `Default Value or Binding` for this column, I find `(getdate())`. How can I make it so it is only computed on create and otherwise can be changed?

Comment: @EdwardTanguay The Default value will prevent EF from updating this column. You could instead remove the default and create an insert trigger. If triggers aren't an option, you could remove the default and override `SaveChanges()` in your EF code. Then you could set the initial value when the `EntityState` is `Added`.

Comment: But I can overwrite this default value with SQL e.g. `UPDATE USERS SET CreatedOn = GETDATE() WHERE id = 44`. However, I can't overwrite it via Entity Framework until I set `StoredGeneratedPattern="None"` in my .edmx files instead of `<Property Name="CreatedOn" Type="datetime" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Computed" />`. But if I do that, then Entity Framework for some reason won't allow SQL Server to apply the default value, i.e. new records have for this value `0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000`.

Comment: The problem is that Entity Framework, even when I specify `StoredGeneratedPattern="None"` for this column in the .edmx file, sends a value which then overwrites the database default: `INSERT [dbo].[Users]([LoginName], [Password], ..., [CreatedOn]) VALUES (@0, @1, ..., @7) where @7 = '0001-01-01 00:00:00' (Type = DateTime2)`.

Comment: `StoredGeneratedPattern` is for generated columns. If you set it to `None`, EF will need a value for the field every time you update the row. If you want to remove the default and update the column whenever you choose, you should remove the attribute entirely. If you take the default off your SQL Server column and regenerate your model, it should do this. I'll try and create a working example and post it in my answer later.

Comment: What I would like to do is (1) allow SQL Server to set the default when created, e.g. as it is now with `Default Value or Binding`, and (2) be able to change this value at any time via Entity Framework.

Comment: @EdwardTanguay Sure. I've got an example of that working. I'll update my answer in a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks for this example. Do you have an `.edmx` file and did you set the `StoreGeneratedPattern` attribute, e.g. `<Property Name="CreatedOn" Type="datetime2" Precision="7" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="None"/>`?

Comment: I have the `StoreGeneratedPattern` attribute set to `Computed`, i.e. <Property Name="CreatedOn" Type="datetime2" Precision="7" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Computed"/>` so that the initial value will be set. But when I do this, while I can save values in other fields with the LINQ statement you provided, it doesns't work with CreatedOn. It acts as if it saved, and I can see it in the object in Visual Studio right before it executes `db.SaveChanges(), but the `CreatedOn` field in the database retains its original value.

Comment: @EdwardTanguay Ah, this is probably the issue. Use `Default Value or Binding` to set the initial date on SQL Server through Management Studio. Don't touch the `Computed Column Specification` or you won't be able to alter the field through EF. When you regenerate the EDMX this should leave the `StoreGeneratedPattern` for `CreatedOn` as `None` and you will be able to update the field as normal. I've added images showing my settings to the post above.